# fail to build project with ndk

Tags: android-ndk

When I try to build my android project with JNI, with Android NDK r9. I can not build the project and come to this error. 
dirname: opérande manquant Saisissez « dirname --help » pour plus d'informations. /bin/sh: 1: ndk-build: not found /bin/sh: 1: ndk-build: not found

This message indicates that my project is not built properly

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak french, but from what I read you have to add the ndk installation directory to your path. Something like

```
export PATH=$PATH:<path/to/your/ndk/>
```

I suggest reading https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#GetStarted